# TextInput is multiline in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm having some issues with **TextInput** in react-native.

I've enabled multiline, and when the function **onChange** is fired, I want to know whether or not *TextInput* is currently in multiline mode.

The only solution I've found so far is checking if the *.nativeEvent.contentSize.height* parameter of the **onChange** function is bigger than **lineHeight** + 20.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: `multiline` is either on or off and the component does not expose the current  'state' of this prop - that is to say, there isn't one. Under the hood, I suspect this just allows the enter key to be used to insert a CRLF. So, would it be easer to check for `\r\n` inside the value after `onChange`? This might work ok for you.

Comment: I just tried this option, unfortunately `\r\n` is added to the text only if the consumer has deliberately added a new line

Comment: So in that case you want to know when it wraps due to content width?

Comment: exactly, as I mentioned checking `lineHeight + 20 < event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height` works, but I think that it's way to fragile

Comment: You could also work out how many average size chars fit in a single line (based on your width) but this would be just as flimsy. Difficult one, I'll update on here if I ever find something that helps you.

Out of interest does `onContentSizeChange` ever fire on iOS due to the fixed height - you mentioned below it doesn't fire on Android.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get back to you regarding your question...

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop for listening to content size change called `onContentSizeChange`. You should use that to check if it's multiline or not.

Comment: I'm using a `TextInput` with fixed height. In Android, `onContentSizeChange` is only risen when I change the size of the height of the `TextInput` (which I never do). So the `onContentSizeChange` event is never risen. –

Answer (score 0):

```
 render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        multiline={true}
        style={{
          height: this.state.inputHeight
        }}
        onContentSizeChange={ this._onTextContentSizeChange }/>
    );
  }

  _onTextContentSizeChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Calls when size changes");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hidden Text component which keeps the same content with the TextInput. Then measure numberOfLines of that Text to check if it's multiline.